# Relationship between Sheet and Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

As to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb507946.aspx) the basic document structure of a SpreadsheetML document consists of the Sheets and Sheet elements, which reference the worksheets in the Workbook.

For example, there is one workbook with sheets:

```
<workbook xmlns=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
    <sheets>
        <sheet name="MySheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" /> 
        <sheet name="MySheet2" sheetId="2" r:id="rId2" /> 
    </sheets>
</workbook>
```

And two worksheets such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1">
            <c r="A1">
                <v>100</v> 
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
</worksheet>
```

My task is to get Worksheet by name of its Sheet.
But I don't understand what is relationship beetwen Sheet and Worksheet.
Ok, I found Sheet with expected name "MySheet2" in Sheets, but how can I get appropriate Worksheet? Worksheet class doesn't have name-attributes or some "foreign keys" to link with Sheet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is correct in that you need to use the relationship id but you can simplify your code a little by using the [`Descendants<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc801003%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [`GetPartById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpartcontainer.getpartbyid%28v=office.14%29.aspx) methods:

```
//find the sheet by name
Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(
                    s => s.Name.ToString().Equals(sheetName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

if (sheet != null)
{
    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    //get the worksheetpart by Id
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    //get the sheetdata from the worksheet
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'v solved it.
There is relationship ID in Sheet.
Simple example here:

```
    string sheetName = "MySheet2";
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"path\to\file", false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Cast<Sheet>().ToList();

        //  Get and remember id of sheet with sheetName
        string rId = "";
        sheets.ForEach(x => { if (x.Name.Value == sheetName)   rId = x.Id.Value; });

        //  Go through the WorksheetParts and find workbookPart with RelationshipId = rId
        foreach (var w in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            string partRelationshipId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(w);

            if (partRelationshipId == rId)
            {
                SheetData sheetData = w.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```